# SQL reservation hotel room

Tags: php, mysql

I want to create a reservation hotel's room using PHP, and to see any available rooms, I use query like this:

```
SELECT * FROM m_room WHERE room_id NOT IN 
(SELECT order_room FROM m_order WHERE 
'$start' >= order_bookstart AND '$end' <  order_bookend) 
ORDER BY room_name
```

`$start` and `$end` is input from a textbox. User first fill the start input and end input, after click search, it will show any available rooms. From my query, If my example data that exist in m_order is: `room_id->1; start-> 2015-05-13; end-> 2015-05-16`

then when I fill `$start` with : **2015-05-14** and `$end` with : **2015-05-15**, it works normally, room_id no. 1 won't shows up, but if I fill the date `$start` with : **2015-05-14** and `$end` with: **2015-05-19**, room_id no. 1 still shows up, which must be not because still used by a client from 2015-05-13 till 2015-05-16

So, **how to fix my query to show any available rooms?**

Comment: In order to keep the code simpe, I'd use a tinyint flag which is either 1 or 0, depending on the room being reserved or not.

Comment: Start < book_end and end > book_start

Comment: Are `order_bookstart` and `order_bookend` defined as Date or  DateTime?

Comment: @Misunderstood I'm using Date.

Comment: @Strawberry not working

Comment: @YUNOWORK if I'm using that, my teacher said it's not good for the apps, he told me to search another idea

Comment: Well, you get the idea. This question is asked frequently enough anyway

Comment: @Strawberry Yes, that's why my query like any answer on that same question, but in my case it doesn't work, that's why I need another query. I have the idea, even I have the logic, but i can't translate my logic to query.

Comment: @CrossVander Then your teacher doesn't have a lot of experience in programming apps. It's a tinyint value, that won't hurt the performance or the datalimit for smartphones. But it makes the code 10 times more readable and easier to understand and/or expand. Which is the extremely important. If your teacher says something else, show him this comment. And if you, teacher, read this: "You have no idea about programming apps."

Comment: If you use a flag though, you still need the date range otherwise, how can you tell when the room is booked??

Comment: if you have a flag, you need a scheduled task that runs every day to execute the query that we're trying to come up with here, and then update the room table.  so you still have the same problem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you might be taking the wrong approach.  You want to find rooms which are available for the whole period, which means if there is ANY booking that has either a start, or an end date, that encompasses either the start or end date of the period you are looking for, it must be rejected.

We can use `where not exists` to accomplish this. For example, for checking if there is a room available from the 14th to the 15th:

```
select *
  from m_room
  where not exists (
    select 1
      from order_room
      where room_id = m_room.room_id
        and ('2015-05-14' between start_date and end_date   
          or '2015-05-15' between start_date and end_date
          or start_date between '2015-05-14' and '2015-05-15')
   );
```

[demo here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/3e636/4)

As a second option, you could also `left join` to the `order_room` table, putting the date range in the join criteria, and then checking for rows where the `order_room` values are `null`.

```
select *
  from m_room
    left join order_room
      on m_room.room_id = order_room.room_id
        and ('2015-05-14' between start_date and end_date
          or '2015-05-15' between start_date and end_date
          or start_date between '2015-05-14' and '2015-05-15')
  where start_date is null;
```

[this demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/3e636/8) has the `left join` option as well, showing the results are equivalent.  This method has the advantage that you get two meaningful results - it shows you the rooms that are definitely available, and if you remove the `where` clause, it will also show you the booking times that conflict for the other rooms.

If you want to allow check-in/check-out on the same day that overlaps another bookings check-out/check-in days, we just need to modify the date range by one day, like so:

```
select *
  from m_room
  where not exists (
    select 1
      from order_room
      where room_id = m_room.room_id
        and ('2015-05-16' between start_date and end_date - interval 1 day
          or '2015-05-20' between start_date - interval 1 day and end_date
          or start_date between '2015-05-16' and '2015-05-20')
   );
```

OR

```
select *
  from m_room
    left join order_room
      on m_room.room_id = order_room.room_id
        and ('2015-05-16' between start_date and end_date - interval 1 day
          or '2015-05-20' between start_date - interval 1 day and end_date
          or start_date between '2015-05-16' and '2015-05-20')
  where start_date is null;
```

Comment: That's what I was trying to get across, but with much less grace! Guess I shouldn't try answering questions first thing in a morning :-(

Comment: First thing in the morning isn't good for anything except going back to sleep.

Comment: I'd do just that if I didn't have to go to work! Hopefully your answer will help the OP and it can be marked as answered

Comment: Using Your first method, It's work great... but still not perfect, in reservation if someone checkout at 16 May 2015, other customer can book it right? Because people check in and check out at 12PM. How to create this working query with that condition? Or it impossible?

Comment: it's not impossible, but you didn't mention time anywhere in your question.  The simplest solution is to simply subtract one day from the end_date for checking the start of the new booking, and add one to the start_date for checking the end of the new booking.

Comment: I added a modified query that supports that

Comment: @CrossVander not so fast.. noticed a small bug where the new booking totally surrounded an old booking. i've updated it again to include that corner case. it still needs the day modification for same day checkin/checkout, but everything you need should be there now

Comment: Ok! Got it... I don't see that problem but I use it if You suggest it. Thanks again.

Comment: Yeah, but time is still linear. An event cannot end before it begins.

Answer (score 0):

Room ID 1 will show up with the second query because the end date entered is after the order_bookend, so I'd imagine you will need to check the start date entered us between. A booking start and end, or the entered end date is between a booking start and end

```
WHERE ('$start'>= order_bookstart OR '$start'< order_bookend) OR 
('$end'>= order_bookstart OR '$end'< order_bookend)
```

Comment: @steven it works good but not perfect, at reservation, if I check out at 2015-05-16 I can start booking again from 2015-05-16. with Your query it can't shows up if I search from 2015-05-16 till some date... and if i search from 2015-05-17 till 2015-05-19 room 1 still not shows up... :D

Comment: You could change >= to >. The concept of my answer was to demonstrate that you need to check the start and end date separately, rather than just check the start is after the booking start and the end is before the booking end, as the date range you enter could start before a booking start and entered end after a booking end date whilst my answer isn't 100% correct, I was (hopefully!) Getting the concept across

Comment: thanks for reply, this question has answered perfectly by pala_

Comment: Its the answer I was trying to provide, just wasn't very well explained. I'll know for next time so I can get the coveted green tick! I'm glad you found a solution to your problem

Answer (score 0):

Consider the following

```
  1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 

A |---|

B    |-----|

C            |----|

D   |-----------|
```

The test for overlaps is simpler than pala and others seem to appreciate.

Event B overlaps event A because event B starts before event A ends, and ends after event A starts.

Event C does NOT overlap event B because although event C ends after event B starts, it starts after event B ends

Event D overlaps all the other events because event D starts before all of the other events end, and ends after all the other events start.

So the test for overlaps is simply:

```
y_start < x_end AND y_end > x_start
```

Answer (score -1):

In order for the room to not be included in the search results, the WHERE condition should cover the following cases:

```
a) bookstart----start--------bookend-------end------------

b) -------------start--------bookstart-----end-----bookend

c) -------------start--bookstart--bookend--end------------

d) bookstart----start----------------------end-----bookend
```

In other words, either **bookstart** or **bookend** is between **start** and **end** (cases a - c), or **bookstart** is before **start** and **bookend** is after **end** (case d):

So the correct SQL should look like this:

```
WHERE (order_bookstart >= $start AND order_bookstart < $end) OR
(order_bookend >= $start AND order_bookend < $end) OR 
(order_bookstart < $start AND order_bookend > $end)
```

Comment: Sorry, but it's not working.. but this question has been answered... thanks for reply.

Comment: it's strange, but anyway it's good that you got a correct answer:)